# Renaming columns for one dataframe renames for a second df

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do two joins in pandas. I have two columns of image file names in one df(`ListDf`). One columns is for old images, and the other is for updated images. I have a master of list of all images from a database that includes the path to the images (`ImageDf`). I want to do a left join of `ListDf` and `ImageDf` to move the paths to the updated images into `ListDf`, and then repeat the left join, this time moving the paths of the old images into `ListDf`. I am doing this by making two copies of `ImageDf`.

```
OldImgList = ImageDf
NewImgList = ImageDf
```

Then I am trying to rename the columns for `OldImgList` and `NewImgList` so that when the join occurs they have the correct column names in `ListDf`

```
OldImgList.columns = ['OldDateMod', 'OldFileName', 'OldPath']
NewImgList.columns = ['NewDateMod', 'NewFileName', 'NewPath']
```

However when I run the first line of code, the column names for both `OldImgList` and `NewImgList` get set to the names in the first line. Then when I run the second line, `OldImgList` takes the column names of `NewImgList`. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is create two references to the same dataframe.

If you want to create two copies of a dataframe, you can use the `df.copy()` method ([link to docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)):

```
OldImgList = ImageDf.copy(deep=True)
NewImgList = ImageDf.copy(deep=True)
```

I'm not following your sequence of joins, but there is likely a way to do it without making 2 copies of your dataframe (which will use more memory). For example, you can supply `lsuffix` or `rsuffix` arguments to `df.join()` to add a string suffix to the left or right dataframe in a join so that matching columns are distinguished from each other ([see docs for more](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)).

Comment: Great thank you! That solved my issue, and I learned something new. Thanks for linking the docs. I thought I had the ```join``` docs well enough, but I had missed the suffix portion.